# RTL8192EE wifi not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet, lenovo

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 17.10 Dual Booted on a Lenovo Thinkpad t440s. Network card is RTL8192EE. The wifi may connect for only a few seconds, then completely drops and no networks are visible. Lots on startup the internet won't connect at all, but once in a while the internet will randomly work perfectly until the computer sleeps. This, however has only happened a few times. So I'm looking for a way to fix my network connectivity issues.

I have browsed a number of fixes on various forums and this one seemed to help, but the problem persisted after 2 reboots:
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7#TOC-Realtek-RTL8192EU-chipset-0bda:818b-

This seems to be a popular issue, however I still have not found a solution that works. Any help would be great, as I am new to linux.

Comment: you can disable power management with `sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off` . use `iwconfig` to see if it has indeed been disabled

Comment: Thanks guys. I have turned power saving off and will see how that turns out. How can i reload the kernel module though? This is my first time running linux so it's still pretty new to me.